# Pages: How to put a word between horizontal rules

Tags: pages

How can I make something that looks like this?

--------   Text   ---------

where the horizontal rules extend to the margin on either side?

Answer (score 3):

With **Pages** it helps to think in terms of layers.  Combinations of Text Boxes and Line graphics layered and arranged, should achieve the desired result.  Determine beforehand if the graphic and text box should cause wrapping and/or move with the rest of the text in the document or remain static.

#### Create a Horizontal Rule with Text Centered

- Add a **Line** graphic to the canvas (Just one line will do)

[image: Add Graphic to document]

- Position the line horizontally to the desired width
- Set the **Object Placement** properties in the **Arrange** tab on the **Inspector** as desired.

[image: Object placement inspector]

- Add a **Text Box** setting the **Text** style Alignment properties to Center and Middle

[image: Text box inspector settings]

- ***IMPORTANT:*** Change the background color from *None* to a color matching your document's background.  (White typically)
- Set the **Object Placement** properties as desired
- Position the text box over the line.  Use the alignment guides to center on the page

[image: Desired result - text centered over a horizontal rule]

By using layers, one can create many interesting effects.  Some of them can be explored by examining the built in templates.

Comment: Nice & simple ;).

Answer (score 0):

———————————————————————Now is the time——————————————

I don't know if it helps, I use Pages quite a lot, and when I run into layout problems I tend to resort to a Text Box. Then place/extend the box to whatever I require.
Use the Arrange function, Object placement, "Stay on Page". Text Wrap, "None", Allowing me to move the box to required location. Also with the facility of moving the box, close to or over any other object or typing.