# I would like to get text in between line in pages

Tags: pages

Am planning to make a resume in pages. I want some of the sub headings to come in between lines. I have attached the image which I want to add in my document.Can somebody please help me?

[image: The way summary and highlights are written in the image attached]

I am able to get a line below the word summary picture below,

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212883/120171) can help?

Answer (score -1):

Make some ------------ reduce the spacing to -30% will give you a line type your txt highlight it increase the spacing to 0 make some spaces inside your txt cut and past them to the sides of your txt

```
           ————————————————  SELECTION ——————————————————
```

you will need to increase the spacing again on the next line also. better still put it in a txt box , copy and paste for the next one just change txt .there are probably other ways